# Using sed with a custom function fails

Tags: sed

I'm having a huge csv file that is url encoded.

I would like to decode all lines, and I thought **sed** could do the trick for me, but I can't make it work.

Here's my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function urldecode() {
    # urldecode <string>
    # from https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649

    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}

export -f urldecode

sed -e 's/.*/urldecode &/e' big_file.csv
```

This produces a repeating error message of ***sh: 1: urldecode: not found***

EDIT:
Somehow, this seems to work in one shell, but not in a different shell.
It works in Git Bash on Windows - but not in the Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows. Both are running GNU bash 4.4.19, but obviously slightly different builds.

Comment: It will possibly work on systems where `/bin/sh` is symlinked to `bash`, but otherwise I don't think it's possible to export functions to arbitrary subshells in the way that you expect. See for example [Can I “export” functions in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148748/65304)

Answer (score 1):

As @steeldriver pointed out, `sed` will spawn `/bin/sh` which is symlinked to `/bin/dash` in current Ubuntu releases and doesn't support functions. This is because `sed` internally uses `popen`, which *always* spawns `/bin/sh` (see [man popen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man3/popen.3.html)).

If you can't or don't want to [make bash the default shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442510/how-to-use-bash-for-sh-in-ubuntu) and need to use bash functions in sed, you can use the following workaround.

In order to make `/bin/sh` point to `/bin/bash`, we first use [unshare](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/unshare.1.html) to spawn a new bash with a private mount namespace, bindmount `/bin/bash` on `/bin/dash` and then execute the sed command:

```
unshare -m -r bash -c "mount --bind /bin/bash /bin/dash && sed -e 's/.*/urldecode &/e' big_file.csv"
```

That way, all exported functions are preserved. You can also write a function so you don't have to write the whole unshare... part all the time, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

function mysed() {
    sedcommand=sed
    # restore quotes around each script
    while test $# -gt 0; do
        [[ "$1" == "-e" ]] && { shift; sedcommand="$sedcommand -e '$1'"; } || sedcommand="$sedcommand $1"; shift
    done
    unshare -m -r bash -c "mount --bind /bin/bash /bin/dash && $sedcommand"
}

function urldecode() {
    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}

export -f urldecode

mysed -e 's|.*|urldecode &|e' big_file.csv
```

Be aware, though, that the `-r` option of `unshare`, which is needed to be able to bindmount, creates a kind of virtual environment in which you are root. Read/write permissions are the same as the user who called `unshare`, but uid and gid will be  0. For example, if you call `whoami` inside `urldecode`, it will print `root`.

You could also simply run the whole script using unshare:

```
unshare -m -r bash -c "mount --bind /bin/bash /bin/dash && ./script.sh"
```

...but the restrictions from the previous paragraph apply.